# No widgets available in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I have no options anywhere for desktop widgets in Windows 7.

At first, I thought it was because of my UAC settings, so I looked into registry hacks for that. The sidebar registry setting is apparently located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SidebarSettings`, and I don't have that key.

Are widgets not included in Windows 7 Professional? How can I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gadgets [are included](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/gadgets.aspx) with Windows 7 Professional. Right clicking Desktop -> Gadgets should get you the options to add them.

Else move over to `Control Panel` -> `Appearance & Personalization` -> `Desktop Gadgets`

[image: gadgets]

---

If it's not there, Head over to `Control Panel` -> `Programs` -> `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off` and put a checkmark against Windows Gadgets platform

[image: install-gadgets]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case: http://i51.tinypic.com/ibc19u.png | http://i52.tinypic.com/2ci7e5t.png

Comment: Updated @Corey.